# Why does plt.imshow(im, cmap='gray') not show a grayscale image?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I am attempting to run a DCT transform on an image. I have tried to make my image a grayscale image with the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy

from numpy import pi
from numpy import sin
from numpy import zeros
from numpy import r_
from scipy import signal
from scipy import misc
import matplotlib.pylab as pylab

#matplotlib inline
pylab.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (20.0, 7.0)

im = misc.imread("indoorPictureResize.jpg")

#show the image
f = plt.figure()
plt.imshow(im,cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

However I receive the image but it's color channel has not changed. Have I done something wrong or is it something I should change?

Answer (score 6):

The array `im` is probably a 3-D array, with shape `(m, n, 3)` or `(m, n, 4)`.  Check `im.shape`.

From the [`imshow`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) docstring: *"`cmap` is ignored if X is 3-D"*.

To use a colormap, you'll have to pass a 2-D array to `imshow`.  You could, for example, plot one of the color channels such as `im[:,:,0]`, or plot the average over the three channels, `im.mean(axis=2)`.  (But if `im` has shape `(m, n, 4)`, you probably don't want to include the alpha channel in the mean.)

Answer (score 0):

Add the `mode` in [scipy.misc.imread](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imread.html) like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy

from numpy import pi
from numpy import sin
from numpy import zeros
from numpy import r_
from scipy import signal
from scipy import misc
import matplotlib.pylab as pylab

#matplotlib inline
pylab.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (20.0, 7.0)

im = misc.imread("indoorPictureResize.jpg", mode="L")

#show the image
f = plt.figure()
plt.imshow(im,cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you. It changed to gray scale.